# Serialize Json to model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't figure out, how to convert a Json input into a c# model.

Here is an example of the Json my controller gets :

```
 [{"name":"StartDate",
   "value":"0",
   "Processors":[[{"processor":{"ProcessorName":"searchAndReplace","ProcessorParameters":[{"ParameterName":"toto"},{"ParameterName":"taa"}]}},
                  {"processor":{"ProcessorName":"searchAndReplace","ProcessorParameters":[{"ParameterName":"toto"},{"ParameterName":"tuuut"}]}}]]},
   {"name":"EndDate","value":"1","Processors":[[]]},
   {"name":"Country","value":"2","Processors":[[]]}]
```

Here is the signature of my controller :

```
public JsonResult SendMapping(List<Mapping> MyMappings)
```

This is my class "Mapping" :

```
public class Mapping
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Processor> Processors { get; set; }
}
```

And then my "ProcessorModel"

```
public enum ProcessorNames { SearchAndReplace }

public class ProcessorModel
{
    public Processor processor;
}

public class Processor
{
    public ProcessorNames ProcessorName;
    public List<Parameter> ProcessorParameters;
}

public class Parameter
{
    public List<string> ParameterName;
}
```

So far, I can get all the **name** and **value**. I can also retrieve the first **ProcessorName**, but not its parameters, nor other **ProcessorNames**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a useful tool when you struggle with JSON to Class conversion.

http://json2csharp.com/

This is very useful to win time. Because I have spend a lot of unnecessary time on debugging JSON de-serialization in the past.

Comment: My Json was wrong, and your tool helped me to understand it. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the ProcessorModel.

You're mapping class should just contain:

```
   public List<Processor> Processors { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
  public List<ProcessorModel> Processors { get; set; }
```

Comment: It helps a bit, but not that much. In fact, with the code I provided, I wasn't able to read the first ProcessorName. With your change, I was able again, but I can't get the rest of the data

Answer (score 1):

`{"ParameterName":"toto"}` is defined in your json (string) as a string and in the POCO you have it as `public List<string> ParameterName;` the json string should be `{"ParameterName":["toto"]}`

Answer (score 1):

I also don't think your JSON is quite right.

It should be

```
[{
"name": "StartDate",
"value": "0",   
"Processors": [{
    "processor": {"ProcessorName": "searchAndReplace",
    "ProcessorParameters": [{
            "ParameterName": "toto"
        },
        {
            "ParameterName": "taa"
        }]},        
    "processor": {"ProcessorName": "searchAndReplace",
    "ProcessorParameters": [{
            "ParameterName": "toto"
        },
        {
            "ParameterName": "taa"
        }]},
},
{
    "processor": {"ProcessorName": "searchAndReplace",
    "ProcessorParameters": [{
            "ParameterName": "toto"
        },
        {
            "ParameterName": "taa"
        }]},        
    "processor": {"ProcessorName": "searchAndReplace",
    "ProcessorParameters": [{
            "ParameterName": "toto"
        },
        {
            "ParameterName": "taa"
        }]},
}]
```

}]

Comment: You were right, this is my Json that was no well created. I've edited your answer and accepted it

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me there is some issue related with lowercase and uppercase property names in your json. Property/Key name must be in same case as defined in class. Please correct that and use below class to Serialize or desalinize.

```
public class JsonHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// JSON Serialization
        /// </summary>
        public static string JsonSerializer<T>(T t)
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(ms, t);
            string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            ms.Close();
            return jsonString;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// JSON Deserialization
        /// </summary>
        public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(string jsonString)
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
            T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
            return obj;
        }
    }
```